# Datanode not up while running TeraSort

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata, master-slave

I have 4 slaves (including master). I get this error in one of my slaves when I run TeraSort. The DataNodes are up before running, but when I run one of my DataNodes die and the computations are done by the rest of 3 slaves:

```
INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: writeBlock blk_-5677299757617064640_1010 received exception java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

2015-03-12 16:42:06,835 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(192.168.0.115:50010, storageID=DS-518613992-192.168.0.115-50010-1426203432424, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020):DataXceiver

java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer (this is one error same log same run )

2015-03-12 16:42:09,809 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: DatanodeRegistration(192.168.0.115:50010, storageID=DS-518613992-192.168.0.115-50010-1426203432424, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020): Exception writing block blk_2791945666924613489_1015 to mirror 192.168.0.112:50010

java.io.IOException: Broken pipe(Second error)

2015-03-12 16:42:09,824 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: writeBlock blk_2791945666924613489_1015 received exception java.io.EOFException: while trying to read 65557 bytes(third error same run)
```

I am stuck in this. Any help is appreciated!

Task Tracker Log:

```
 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed validating JVM
java.io.IOException: JvmValidate Failed. Ignoring request from task: attempt_201503121637_0001_m_000040_0, with JvmId: jvm_201503121637_0001_m_-2136609016
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.validateJVM(TaskTracker.java:3278)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.statusUpdate(TaskTracker.java:3348)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)
2015-03-12 16:43:02,577 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController: Exit code from task is : 143
2015-03-12 16:43:02,577 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController: Output from DefaultTaskController's launchTask follows:
2015-03-12 16:43:02,577 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController:
2015-03-12 16:43:02,577 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201503121637_0001_m_1555953113 exited with exit code 143. Number of tasks it ran: 1
2015-03-12 16:43:02,599 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201503121637_0001_m_000054_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
2015-03-12 16:43:02,599 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Received commit task action for attempt_201503121637_0001_m_000048_0
2015-03-12 16:43:02,599 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Trying to launch : attempt_201503121637_0001_m_000054_0 which needs 1 slots
2015-03-12 16:43:02,600 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskLauncher : Waiting for 1 to launch attempt_201503121637_0001_m_000054_0, currently we have 0 free slots
2015-03-12 16:43:03,618 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201503121637_0001_m_1496188144 given task: attempt_201503121637_0001_m_000051_0
```

Answer (score 0):

The TaskTracker logs are more descriptive. Can you show whats there in the log?

Also check if the servers are running on the correct ports.

You can try doing this, copy and replace the hadoop core jar from the working datanode to the failing datanode and restart the mapreduce service.

And one more thing to check, on the working datanode do netstat to see on which port the tasktracker server is running, then check if the tasktracker service is running on the same port on the failing node.

I guess the default port is 50060 for tasktracker.

So since the ports are fine, connection reset by peer happens when the request made by the reduce task is not fulfilled, or the result is truncated , it might also happen if it could not find the appropriate file(can also happen because of permissions).

Comment: It is running correctly, I have no clue with the errors :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The problem was I was doing SSH through root to my slaves , the communication between the job tracker and task tracker is too frequent , hence the issue (connection refused by peer). I set up a password-less SSH connection between master and slave , it works fine now.(you need to SSH through hduser or the user created in the hadoop group)

Thanks Sahitya for your time and help!Appreciate it!

-Vinod

Comment: Thank you, that was informative. But when you say it worked after you set up password less ssh , did you not do that before installing hadoop?